# Set color of Highcharts series bar based on value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, highcharts

I have [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0fKrvLbcQndqj0gl1bh?p=preview) where I am playing with Highcharts. I was wondering if it was possible to set the color of a bar based on the value of that bar. Right now I have 5 bars that are changing on an interval between 0 and 100, and I want the colors of the bars to reflect the number range they are in. Like

`0 < x < 25` is neutral color

`25 < x < 50` is yellow

`50 < x < 75` is orange

`75 < x < 100` is red

I am familiar with the series methods in the api, but I dont really see anything about changing the color for the series. I have previously done this using chart js but I am trying my hand at highcharts since it is used more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this in your plunker link after you randomize the datasets, at the bottom of the interval, and it changed the line color

`$scope.chart.series[0].update( {color: "red"} );`

Honestly, why not write a function that fires at the start of the interval that generates the numbers and an associated color based on the number, and then set the numbers and colors accordingly. Use an array of objects or something.

I leave the function as an exercise for you to solve.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I updated the plunker with a so so solution to see if it worked. Any idea why I may have lost the animation on all but one bar? The animations were working when I hadn't changed the colors, but once I did they stop on all but one

Answer (score 0):

In your series array that is returned via your ajax call, you can set a "color" property that will color the bar to that color.

In your plunker I added the following line right after `$scope.jsondata = ret;`:

```
$scope.jsondata[0].color = "red";
```

That did change the bar to red.  So you could either do it on the server side and return it to your JS, or before you set the series in the HighChart, you could call a simple method to check the value and set the color property.